# How to add karaoke lyrics like effect in wordpress ( how to use rabbit lyrics plugin )?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

Please check out quran.com's interactive text reading guide kinda software to get an idea of what i am talking about.

i have a friend who wants a poetry section in her blog where she can record herself reading the poems and let the readers/listeners run the audio like a kinda lyrical video or something (where the text colour progresses with the audio. her website is setup using wordpress hence it will be great if you could suggest something that uses wordpress, otherwise i will have to create a separate page for her poetry posts.

i tried to do a text animation along with an audio player and worked fine but required a lot of calibration and adjustment to make sure that the voice and animation synced, which the girl cannot do everytime.

EDIT: I found a plugin called Rabbit Lyrics which has the functionality I require, but the instructions are not really helpful and we don't know how to use it in wordpress. can you take a look at their github documentation and let me know how do i add rabbit lyrics block in a post?

https://github.com/guoyunhe/rabbit-lyrics-wp